# $location inside a $timeout in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, timeout, location

I have a controller in AngularJS, with $timeout and $location in the header.
The controller has the following code:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $location.path("/nextview")}, 500, false)
}
```

Due to the async nature of the $timeout, it seems that $location isn't passed, and therefore fails. If I put $location as part of the function arguments, it still doesn't work.

```
$timeout(function ($location) {
    $location.path("/nextview")}, 500, false)
}
```

However if I have only the below, it works:

```
    $location.path("/nextview")};
```

I really need some sort of timeout as the code before the location change is to give the user a visual cue. If the location is changed immediately, there's no visual cue.

Is there a better method to do a pause or sleep, maybe synchronously?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it like this

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $location.path("/nextview");
    });
}, 2000);
```

If this doesn't work, check your console for any errors.